# Building an interactive Chart in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, charts

I am attempting to build an interactive chart that the user can select and mark up individual data points within the graph. I am using Visual Studio 2012 in C# windows forms.  I am new to programming and would appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Its not a lack of research.  I have used the RadTools addon.  The biggest problem is I am unsure what to call something like this.  I have tried searching the forums, but without the right terms, I get wrong results.  If someone could at least point me to the right term to research towards i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use mschart control here is the link http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: This appears to be a great start.  I breezed through this option online but was unsure what they meant about interactivity.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Josh Yes they are only static graphs :(

Comment: I guess I should have added in the post what type of data I was implementing.  I am trying to build an FFT analysis chart.